# Multiple Semicolons on one line

Tags: javascript, syntax

Why are multiple semicolons allowed on one line in Javascript? What is really happening here?

```js
var x = 5;;;;;;;;;;
console.log(x);;;;;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907389/double-semicolons-syntax-in-javascript. The semicolon is just a separator, you can habe multiple of the same like you can have multiple new lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A semi colon is a statement separator. By itself it creates an [empty statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/Empty) which, if you can say it is "executed" has no effect.

Multiple semicolons in a row simply create multiple consecutive empty statements and serve no practical purpose in code terms.

Deliberate use of empty statements may cause confusion and usually have alternatives. For example:

```
if( condition)
    ;
else {
   // do something
}
```

is more clearly coded as

```
if( !condition) {
    // do something
 }
```